# How to call a python script from another python script?

Tags: python, import, call

I have a script called errorHandler.py and another script called test.py both in the same directory. I put an error in a try statement in test.py on purpose and i am trying to let the errorHandler.py script catch it. When it executes it does not fail or produce an error but the errorHandler.py script does not launch either. Any help would be appreciated. Below are the two scripts...

```
#--errorHandler.py

# python 3
try:
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import smtplib

# python 2.7
except:
    from Tkinter import *
    import ttk
    import tkMessageBox as messagebox
    import smtplib

class errorHandler:
    def __init__(self, master):

        master.title('Error')
        master.resizable(False, True)
        master.configure(background = 'cornsilk')
        self.mtr = master

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure('TFrame', background = 'cornsilk')
        self.style.configure('TButton', background = 'cornsilk')
        self.style.configure('TLabel', background = 'cornsilk', font = ('Arial', 11))
        self.style.configure('Header.TLabel', font = ('Arial', 18, 'bold'))

        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_header.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, text = "ERROR", foreground = 'red', style = 'Header.TLabel', justify = 'center').grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, wraplength = 300,
              text = ("Please fill out the following form to help identify this error.  "
                      "Doing so will help make improvements to this program.")).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_content.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Name:').grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, sticky = 'sw')
        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Email:').grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, sticky = 'sw')
        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Comments:').grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, sticky = 'sw')

        self.entry_name = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, width = 24, font = ('Arial', 10))
        self.entry_email = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, width = 24, font = ('Arial', 10))
        self.text_comments = Text(self.frame_content, width = 50, height = 10, font = ('Arial', 10))

        self.entry_name.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5)
        self.entry_email.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.text_comments.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5)

        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = 'Send',
               command = self.send).grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'e')
        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = 'Clear',
               command = self.clear).grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')

        self.hdBtn = Button(self.frame_content, text='Hide Details', command = self.hideDetails)
        self.hdBtn.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')
        self.hdBtn.grid_remove()

        self.swBtn = ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text='Show Details', command = self.showDetails)
        self.swBtn.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')

        self.frame_Details = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_Details.pack()

        self.text_comments_Det = Text(self.frame_Details, width = 50, height = 10, font = ('Arial', 10))
        self.text_comments_Det.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5)
        self.text_comments_Det.grid_remove()

    def send(self):
        msg = 'Name: \t\t%s\n\n' % self.entry_name.get() \
        +'Contact: \t\t%s\n\n' % self.entry_email.get() \
        +'Message: \t\t%s\n\n\n' % self.text_comments.get('1.0', END) \
        +'Error Message: \t%s' % self.err
        self.email(msg)
        messagebox.showinfo(title = 'Confirmation', message = 'Message Sent!')
        root.destroy()

    def clear(self):
        self.entry_name.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry_email.delete(0, 'end')
        self.text_comments.delete(1.0, 'end')

    def showDetails(self):
        self.text_comments_Det.grid()
        self.hdBtn.grid()
        self.swBtn.grid_remove()
        self.mtr.geometry("368x520")
        self.text_comments_Det.delete('1.0', END)
        self.text_comments_Det.insert(END, self.err)

    def hideDetails(self):
        self.text_comments_Det.grid_remove()
        self.hdBtn.grid_remove()
        self.swBtn.grid()
        self.mtr.geometry("368x352")

    def err(self):
        try:
            import arcpy, sys, traceback
            # Get the traceback object
            tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
            tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]

            # Concatenate information together concerning the error into a message string
            errs = "\n\n\nPYTHON ERRORS:\n\tTraceback info:\n\t\t" + tbinfo + "\n\t" \
                + "Error Info:\n\t\t" + str(sys.exc_info()[1]) + "\n\n" \
                + 'GEOPROCESSING MESSAGE:\n\t' + arcpy.GetMessages(0) + "\n\n" \
                + 'GEOPROCESSING WARNING:\n\t' + arcpy.GetMessages(1) + "\n\n" \
                + 'GEOPROCESSING ERROR:\n\t' + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n\n"
        except:
            import sys, traceback
            # Get the traceback object
            tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
            tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]

            # Concatenate information together concerning the error into a message string
            errs = "\n\n\nPYTHON ERRORS:\n\tTraceback info:\n\t\t" + tbinfo + "\n\t" \
                + "Error Info:\n\t\t" + str(sys.exc_info()[1]) + "\n\n"
        return errs

    def email(self, txt, toaddrs  = ['skeizer111@gmail.com']):
        fromaddr = 'yourerrorreports@gmail.com'
        msg = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % ("Error Report", txt)
        username = 'yourerrorreports@gmail.com'
        password = 'Alberta01'

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username,password)
        for add in toaddrs:
            server.sendmail(fromaddr, add, msg)
            server.quit()

def runErrRpt():
    root = Tk()
    errorHandler(root)
    root.mainloop()

runErrRpt()




#--test.py
try:
    st = 1+"s"
    print st
except:
    import errorHandler
```

Comment: Is all that code (and tkinter, no less) really necessary for your issue? Could you reduce it to a [MCVE]?

Comment: Works for me on Python 2.7.10 on OS X.  How are you running your script?  Some IDEs have problems running Tk applications.

Answer (score 0):

According to lmgtfy

> Get one python file to run another:
>
> ```
> Put this in main.py: #!/usr/bin/python import yoursubfile.
> Put this in yoursubfile.py #!/usr/bin/python print "hello";
> Run it: python main. py.
> It prints: hello.
> ```